# Create break in .Net Chart series bound to a DataTable

Tags: dotnetcharting

I have a .Net chart where a series is bound to DataTable using .XValueMember and .YValueMember with series ChartType = Line. I would like to prevent a line being drawn between 2 specified sequential items in the DataTable. Is this possible without creating multiple series, and if so,how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to overlay another series with points corresponding to the coordinates of the sequential items using the chart background color, so the section of the line between the items is not visible.